# Que un alert me indique que Fila elimine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Buenos días.

Yo Tengo este código Jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#bt_add').click(function() {
          var check = [];
          $("#tabla").find('.selected').find('td').each(function(){
            if($.trim($(this).text()) === "")
              check.push($(this).attr('id'));
          });
          if(check.length === 0)
            agregar();
          else 
            alert('Registre los Datos de la Fila ');;
      });
      $('#bt_del').click(function() {

        eliminar();
      });

      $('#bt_delall').click(function() {
        eliminarTodasFilas();

      });

    });
    var cont = 0;
    var id_fila_selected = [];

    function agregar() {
      cont++;
      var fila =

        '<tr class="selected" id="fila' + cont + '" onclick="seleccionar(this.id);"><td> </td>' +

        '<td><input type="text" id="nombre"></td>' +

        '<td><input type="text" id="area"></td>' +

        '<td><input type="text" id="puesto"></td>' +

        '<td><input type="text" id="email" onkeyup="addToTable(event)"></td></tr>';

      $('#tabla').append(fila);
      reordenar();
    }

    function addToTable(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        const inputs = row.querySelectorAll('input');
        const values = [].map.call(inputs, input => input.value);
        const tds = row.querySelectorAll('td');
        [].forEach.call(tds, (td, i) => {
          if (i === 0) { td.textContent = i + 1; }
          else { td.innerHTML = values[i - 1]; }
        });
        reordenar()
      }
    }

    function seleccionar(id_fila) {
      if ($('#' + id_fila).hasClass('seleccionada')) {
        $('#' + id_fila).removeClass('seleccionada');
        // borrar también el id del array de filas seleccionadas
        var existe_el_id = id_fila_selected.indexOf(id_fila); 
        id_fila_selected.splice(existe_el_id, 1);
      } else {
        $('#' + id_fila).addClass('seleccionada');
        // agregar id sólo si se hizo click
        id_fila_selected.push(id_fila); 
      }

    }

    function eliminar() {

      for (var i = 0; i < id_fila_selected.length; i++) {
        $('#' + id_fila_selected[i]).remove();
      }
      reordenar();
    }

    function reordenar() {
      var num = 1;
      $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function() {
        $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(num);
        num++;
      });
    }

    function eliminarTodasFilas() {
      $('#tabla tr.selected').each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }

    $(function () {        
          $("table").on("dblclick", "td",function () {                  
              var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
              $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
              $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' >");
              $(this).children().first().focus();
              $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
                  if (e.which == 13) {
                      var newContent = $(this).val();
                      $(this).parent().text(newContent);
                      $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
                      }
                  });
              $(this).children().first().blur(function(){
                  $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
                  $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
                  });
              });
          });
```

El problema aquí es que cuando el usuario elimine una fila me de un aviso (alert) que diga: "elimino la fila **numero de la fila** de la columna **Nombre de la columna** ", Pero yo ingrese lo siguiente:

```js
 $('#bt_del').click(function() {
  alert('Elimino la fila'+ cont );
    eliminar();
  });
```

Lo cual no me dice que fila elimine, mas bien me dice las veces que estoy eliminando una fila.

Por ultimo los campos de las columnas son: Nº, NOMBRE, AREA, PUESTO, EMAIL, espero que me entiendan, aun así les muestro mi código HTML y espero que puedan ayudarme:

```html
<div id="content">
  <label> Tabla de Ejemplo </label>
  <br>
  <div align="center" style="width:416px;">
            <button id="bt_add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
            <button id="bt_del" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar</button>
            <button id="bt_delall" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar todo</button>
             </div>
            <table id="tabla" style="position:absolute;top:150px;left:75px" class="table table-bordered">

            <thead>

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Nº</td>
        <td>NOMBRE</td>
        <td>AREA</td>
        <td>PUESTO</td>
        <td>EMAIL</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Quería ponerle el nuevo código (ya que tengo código basura), pero estaba haciedo otra cosa y se me olvido editarlo

Comment: Hasta ahorita me di cuenta en las notificaciones @Pikoh.

Comment: Disculpe @Pikoh, me podría ayudar con una duda que tengo en este mismo código, es de restricciones (se podría decir)

Comment: Lamentablemente, la programación web no es lo mio. Pero te recomiendo que crees una nueva pregunta. Aunque el código sea el mismo, si la duda es diferente y no tiene nada que ver con esta pregunta, es totalmente aceptable y seguro que encuentras la ayuda que necesitas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parte de **id_fila_selected = [];** también se añade:

```
 function eliminar() {
     var dels = 0;
     var idfilas ="";
     for (var i = 0; i < id_fila_selected.length; i++) {
         idfilas += document.getElementById(id_fila_selected[i]).firstElementChild.textContent + " ... ";
         $('#' + id_fila_selected[i]).remove();
         dels++;

     }
    if (dels==1)
        alert(' Se ha eliminado la fila ' + idfilas);
    else 
        alert(' Se han eliminado las filas ' + idfilas);
     reordenar();
     id_fila_selected=[];


 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo único que tienes que hace es iterar las filas seleccionadas:

```
const ids = id_fila_selected.join();
const yes = confirm(`¿Desea eliminar las filas ${ids}?`);

if (yes) { eliminar(); }
```

El método [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) te permite unir un array por medio de un delimitador (opcional, por defecto se agrega una coma). De esta manera, lo que obtendrás serán todas las filas seleccionadas separados por comas dentro de un string.

Tu función eliminar no sufriría cambios, solo necesitas vaciar el array que contiene los ids de las filas seleccionadas:

```
id_fila_selected = [];
```

Comment: Si se hace esa asignación dentro del handler del boton de eliminar, $(this) hara referencia al propio boton, y el boton no esta en la tabla, como se puede ver en el HTML. No se puede suponer que el boton este dentro, porque el OP ha puesto su codigo HTML y alli se ve claramente que esta fuera. Saludos!

Comment: Tienes mucha razón, no vi bien el código en la app móvil. Gracias por avisar, en un momento edito.

Comment: Hola @GustavoGarcía: Me esta ayudando mucho tu programa solo que me generar un error que he tratado de solucionar pero no he podido. Luego de eliminar una fila, creo otra nueva y al volverla a eliminar me sale este mensaje: ¿Desea eliminar la Fila1,fila2? Cuando solo tengo ingresada en mi tabla una fila, no se por que este contando una fila de mas, ¿A caso usted sabría decirme?

Comment: @ReinosRic Sucede porque no has vaciado el array que contiene los ids seleccionados. Una vez que eliminas las filas, vacía el array que contiene los ids.

Comment: Hola, el **id_fila_selected = [];** ya lo tenia en mi código, esta en la parte donde agrega las filas (debajo del var cont=0;) o ¿es que hay que poner otro **id_fila_selected = [];**?.

Comment: @ReinosRic Claro, debes volver a poner `id_fila_selected = [];` **luego de eliminar las filas**, es decir, después del for.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que en `id_fila_selected` tienes todas las filas que serán eliminadas (porque el usuario las seleccionó), tienes que sacar provecho a esa variable para mostrarlo en un alert.

Como ya tienes la información en ese arreglo, puedes hacer que se muestre con un ciclo:

```
$('#bt_del').click(function() {
    var eliminadas = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < id_fila_selected.length; i++) {
        eliminadas = eliminadas + id_fila_selected[i] + ",";
    }
    alert("Elimino la(s) fila(s): "+eliminadas);
    eliminar();
});
```

En este caso le agregamos una coma, porque pueden ser varias, de acuerdo a como esta estructurado tu código.

No se si lo tienes en alguna otra parte en tu código, pero **recuerda** que tendrías que vaciar el arreglo `id_fila_selected` una vez que termines de eliminar las filas.

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

P.D. No se si el `ToString()` sea necesario, puedes probar con o sin el, es solo que ahorita mismo no puedo probarlo.

Comment: Hola Kenny, al igual que tu código y la de @GustavoGarcia me causa el siguiente error:

Luego de eliminar una fila, creo otra nueva fila y al volver a eliminarla me sale este mensaje: **Elimino la(s) fila(s) fila1,fila2** Cuando solo tengo ingresada en mi tabla una fila, no se por que este contando una fila de mas, ¿A caso usted sabría decirme cual es la causa?.

E investigado por mi cuenta y no he encontrado como solucionarlo.

Comment: Hola Reinos. Como te indique en mi respuesta, es absolutamente necesario que vacies el arreglo id_fila_selected antes de usarlo de nuevo. Porque si no lo haces, solo estas borrando las filas en HTML, pero en JQuery todavia existen porque estan en el arreglo. Creo que esa es la causa.

Comment: Hola @Kenny, también se me olvido comentarte que si poseo en otra parte el código que me mencionas, resulta que **eliminar();** es la verdadera función y "#bt_del" solo llama al ID del botón, esa función de la que te comento se encuentra en la ultima parte del código Javascript.
¿Eso seria realmente lo que afecta para que no vacié los **Arrays**?.
Saludos.

Comment: Pues... no mucho te entendi, pero básicamente lo que te estamos sugiriendo (Gustavo y yo) es que vacies el array, no importa si es en la función `eliminar()` o en la del `"#bt_del"`. En cualquiera de las dos pon esto: `id_fila_selected = [];`